# Example of a Lipschitz function $f$ on $[0,\infty ]$ such that its square $f^{2}$ is **NOT** Lipschitz?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Question:

Can anyone come up with an example of a Lipschitz function $f$ on $[0,\infty ]$ such that its square $f^{2}$ is **NOT** Lipschitz? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

$f(x) = x$.  (If $f$ is bounded and Lipschitz, then I think it's square is Lipschitz.)

Answer (score 4):

Just to amplify Stephen Montgomery-Smith's answer:

The formula $f(x)^2 - f(y)^2 = (f(x) - f(y) ) (f(x) + f(y))$ is helpful in this regard.

Note also that there is a big difference between *Lipschitz* and *locally Lipschitz* in your question.  (The difference of squares formula shows that
the square of a locally Lipschitz function will be locally Lipschitz.)